# Sitecore serialization package installation removes custom roles

Tags: security, serialization

There is a Sitecore 10.2 instance with serializations delivered via Sitecore.CLI v4. Item changes delivered via package and installed using the following command:

```
dotnet sitecore ser pkg install -f "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\serialization.itempackage" --client-id "$(sitecoreClientId)" --client-secret "$(accSitecoreClientSecret)" --cm "$(accSitecoreContentManagementHost)" --auth "$(accSitecoreIdentityHost)" --publish
```

The package contains custom security roles that inherit standard Sitecore ones (like Author etc.). When the roles were included into package for the first time, they were successfully delivered to CM. After *few* deployemts (not the next one), package installation kills them:

```
[role] [D] Role ***\MyProj Content Editor is removed successfully
[role] [D] Role ***\MyProj Limited Content Editor is removed successfully
```

The roles are still in the package under `<module-name>/items/_roles/sitecore` directory. The serialization files look the same as in the initial package. What may cause such a behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We encountered a problem very similar to your question. We started experiencing the issue once upgrading to 10.3 and CLI 5.1.25. In our case, the problem was caused by using a relative file path in `defaultModuleRelativeSerializationPath` like `../../serialization` in the project's `sitecore.json` file.

When using `ser pkg create` this causes the package to construct a corrupted file path for serialized roles within the package (zip) file. Thus the roles are interpreted as empty by `ser pkg install`, dropping all the roles afterward.

[image: Package file opened with WINRAR to see file contents]

*Package file opened with WINRAR to see file contents*

The solution for us was not very straight forward since:

- The construction with `pkg create` and `install` ran apparently stable for a long time.
- You can override file path serialization on the module level, however, you cannot do that for roles.
- Changing it in the root `sitecore.json` will cause issues for all modules.

We ended up adding a new `sitecore.json` config file to the project. In there correcting the `defaultModuleRelativeSerializationPath` to just "serialization" and moving the serialized roles into the folder where the actual module is located. Afterwards calling `ser pkg create` with the extra `--config` parameter referencing the duplicated `sitecore.json` file for creating an itempackage just for roles.

Comment: I've also documented similar behavior when the `defaultModuleRelativeSerializationPath` is set to something like `"items"`.  When I created the item package, all of the standard content ended up in a folder named `serialization` regardless of the `sitecore.json` configuration.  The roles, however, respected this configuration and were put into a folder named `items`.  When I changed the the  `defaultModuleRelativeSerializationPath` to `"serialization"`, this allowed the roles to be installed within the content package.